# How to troubleshoot network issues on macOS

Tags: network, wifi, macos

I have a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina and I've been having issues with the internet connection. Every few minutes (sometimes up to a few hours), all programs connected to the internet stop working. The error is usually a timeout.
The WiFi doesn't disconnect or anything. And if I manually reconnect to the same network it starts working again.

I highly suspect that the issue is with my integrated router, but the router is locked by the ISP so I can't access the logs.

I would like to be able to rule out hardware/software issues in my Mac. How can I analyze this on my Mac?

Comment: Can you have a look at `/var/log/system.log` at a time where your network gets disconnected to see whether there is any information of interest? Is this a new phenomena you can relate to a change made on a Mac or has this been going on for too long?

Comment: There are a number of suggestions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74419/wifi-wont-connect-connection-timeout-mac http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/14/fix-wifi-connection-timeout-error-mac/

Comment: @nohillside It was happening for a while now, I contacted the ISP but they checked and they told me that they fixed the issue(they did replace some stuff). But now I'm starting to think that it might be their equipment, and they don't want to admit it(because im pay for it monthly), but I wanna be sure before buying my own.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee Its not a "timeout" error that you see when connecting to the WIFI. I meant that the software that uses the internet(browser and anything else) show in their console timeout messages.

Comment: if you get errors of any kind, adding a copy (as text if log output, as image if alert box) might give a clue. And I assume you already rebooted the router after they told it it's fixed on their end?

Comment: Limited info to work with; open a terminal window and use the command `ping www.google.com` and have it running constantly. When you get the behaviour the question is about, compare the more normal time value with one that corresponds with netowrk issue. See if it spikes to large numbers. That will show you if there is latency issues creeping in.

Comment: On a lot of isp's you can replace their router with yours.  Find the owners manual for your router.  It may reveal clues for how to get in the router's admin panel.  Do internet search for details.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee Ill try it.

Comment: @historystamp They blocked it completely. The endpoint to the router was replaced with a notice to use the app instead...

Comment: I managed to get the logs from the wifi spot Im connected to(and i suspect is the once causing issues). here are the relevant logs, from when I experienced the problem: https://pastebin.com/YXFq20bw

Comment: So, you only get these message "no addresses available " when you have the issue?  It says it is a problem with ipv6.  WAG turn off ipv6 https://hide.me/en/knowledgebase/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-a-macos-computer/